# ¿Cómo usar setInterval para refrescar un div con valores php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, div, setinterval

estoy tratando de actualizar un div donde hay valores que se extraen en PHP de la base de datos, sin embargo al momento que se refresca el div la función parece que no reconoce valores de la conexión. Dejo mi código. Gracias.

```
<?php 
$maxsp ="SELECT *FROM setpoint_tl264 WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM setpoint_tl264)";
$resultadomaxsp=mysqli_query($conexion,$maxsp);
$row=$resultadomaxsp->fetch_assoc();
$setpoint=$row['valor'];
 ?>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <h4>Manipulación del Setpoint</h4>

  <form id="formsp">
  <div class="form-group">
    <p><label name="" for="">Valor actual:</label> </p>
    <div id="refreshsp" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $setpoint; ?></div>
    <label name="setpoint" for="setpoint">Modificar:</label> <br>
      <input type="range" class="rangosp" max="100" min="0" id="cambiosp" name="cambiosp"  placeholder="0% al 100%">
      <h1 id="variarsp" class="variacionrealsp"><?php echo $setpoint; ?></h1>

  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="verificacionsp" id="verificacionsp" required>
    <label class="form-check-label"  for="exampleCheck1">Verificación</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Cambiar" >
<div id="mostrar_mensaje" ></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Código del javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#refreshsp").load("dataplc/cambiar-sp.php")
}, 13000);
);
```

Esta es la foto del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error te dice que $conexion no está definido antes de ser usado, por lo tanto se supone que lo debes definir antes o bien hacer un include del script que contenga los datos de $conexion

Comment: la conexión es una variable de la conexion de la base de datos.

Comment: sabes como puedo llamar todo junto?

Comment: Debes hacer un `include()` del archivo donde tienes definida la variable $conexion para que ésta sea reconocida después cuando haces la consulta. Si no sabes hacer un `include()` mejor que busques por la red algun tutorial para ello, pues es de lo más básico en PHP.